# OpenVPN and LDAP Groups

Tags: debian, iptables, openvpn

I'm setting an OpenVPN server (Debian9) with LDAP authentication for our company's cloud infrastructure. It works great but now I'd like to restrict access for specific users to some servers. I've defined some LDAP groups and I was wondering if there was any way to restrict access based on these groups. I first thought of assigning a specific IP range to each group and restricting access via IPtables but I think ccd is only user specific.

Do I have to assign an IP to each user or can I specify an IP range to an entire group ?